# Laravel Raw Query and Eloquent ORM relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have created the following Raw Query in order to Rank the posts in my site..

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
->select(DB::raw('*,(score / (NOW() - posts.created_at)) as `ordering_value`'))
->orderBy('ordering_value', 'DESC')
->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'DESC')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id->paginate(12);
```

The only problem I'm facing now is this, by using raw query I can no longer access the eloquent orm relationships, so in my blades I can no longer use post->user...

which kinda suck, meaning I have to rewrite some of my blades.

wanted to ask if anyone know a magic to go around this and not writing my code twice .. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer myself :)

```
$posts = Post::selectRaw('*, (score / (NOW() - posts.created_at)) as `ordering_value`')
           ->orderBy('ordering_value', 'DESC')
           ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(9);
```